# $A$ is local and $A^n$ and $A^m$ are isomorphic as $A$-modules.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

I need to show that $A^n$ and $A^m$ are isomorphic if and only if $n=m$, where $A$ is a local ring ($A$ is a commutative ring with unity). Then need to generalize this to any commutative local ring $A$. I can see how to generalize, I need to use the fact that every ring has a maximal ideal. But don't know how to prove that $n=m$ is necessary. I appreciate it.

Comment: Do you know tensor products?

Comment: @PrinceM No, actually I know the definition of a tensor prouct for vector spaces but don't know much.

Comment: Was this problem assigned in a class? What types of things have you seen and what text are you using.

Comment: I only ask so I can help give you a solution that matches what theory you have at your disposal. Most common way for this one is building some theory of tensor products, but we'll see if we can get around that since you don't have those.

Comment: The idea is you want use the fact that $A/\mathfrak{m}$ is a field, and collapse to an argument about dimension of vector spaces.

Comment: This is an exercise in Undergraduate Commutative Algebra by Reid. So far, I am only exposed to basic abstract algebra (ring theory and an introduction to the theory of modules). This chapter of the book includes the definition of a module, homomorphisms between modules, generators of modules, Cayley-Hamilton theorem and its corollaries (Nakayama's Lemma), and a little discussion about exact sequences.

Comment: Ok, I have a copy of that. Proceed with the hint I give above. See if you can use the isomorphism $\phi: A^n \to A^m$ to induce an isomorphism on $(A_\mathfrak{m})^m \cong (A_\mathfrak{m})^n$. Argue that these spaces can be viewed as vector spaces, thus $n = m$. Does that help get you started?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot.

Comment: We don't need the fact that $A$ is a local ring, right? We do not use it in the argument.

Comment: No, I think that instruction was just to help you discover that modding out by a maximal ideal is a good idea. When people see "local ring" they tend to think "mod out by the maximal ideal". I have never seen this problem assigned for local ring, but always just the general case. I'll have to take a quick look through Reids book to make sure theres not a specific reason he stated it that way.

Comment: If you come up with a proof to your problem it is ok to post an answer to your own question :)

Comment: Okay, I will do that when I have time :) Thanks for your help.